# Wildfly cannot delete deployements files

Tags: java, wildfly, ear

im working with wildfly 14.0 with Netbeans. When i deploy my ear the first time to wildfly  everithing runs ok. But when i try to redeploy it im getting this error:

```
Initial deploying MetacontratasV4-ear to D:\Wildfly\wildfly-14.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\MetacontratasV4-ear-1.0.ear Error during incremental deploy: org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FSException: Cannot delete file MetacontratasV4-web-1.0.war in D:/Wildfly/wildfly-14.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/MetacontratasV4-ear-1.0.ear.
```

If i remove the files manually it works, but to do so first i have to restart wildfly which its time consuming.
Its any other way to redeploy an ear without restarting

Im making the deploys throught netbeans interface.

IF you need any configuration file in order to provide more accurate answer feel free to request me it.

UPDATE
I tryed to deploy the ear using the command line and still getting a similar error
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXSwB.jpg)
So i tryed adding the --force option which outputs me the following

```
10:26:26,104 ERROR [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0010: Couldn't delete content D:\Wildfly\wildfly-14.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\fa\2a2cb037ddd7d2e0066b475c484505caf64cbb: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: D:\Wildfly\wildfly-14.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\fa\2a2cb037ddd7d2e0066b475c484505caf64cbb
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepositoryImpl.removeContent(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:315)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentFullReplaceHandler$1.handleResult(DeploymentFullReplaceHandler.java:190)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtils$2.handleResult(DeploymentHandlerUtils.java:165)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.invokeResultHandler(AbstractOperationContext.java:1533)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1515)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1472)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1455)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1319)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:876)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:756)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1411)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:423)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:265)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:231)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:240)
at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$400(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:138)
at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:158)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:289)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:246)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:158)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$AsyncTaskRunner.run(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:160)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
```

10:26:26,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location D:\Wildfly\wildfly-14.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\fa\2a2cb037ddd7d2e0066b475c484505caf64cbb\content

Comment: Well, you can rename the `war.deployed` to `war.dodeploy` and it will redeploy without a restart...how are you re-deploying at the moment?

Comment: Right now im stopping wildfly them i remove the files, i start it again and then i can  deploy it. Ill try your advice right now.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didnt worked the .deployed file is not the problem but the ear file, also i just realized that the exception tells "file" but in the deployements folder is a folder with that name, and not a file.

Comment: My other guess - *Error during incremental deploy* - are you deploying a new version of the `.ear` file?

Comment: Yes, or at least i think so, before deploying it i run the build command on netbeans so it should override the older version.

Comment: Are you only building the war in Netbeans after deploying an ear ? I guess this could be the cause of your issue, try redeploying the ear and not the war.

Comment: Im building the ear :(

Answer (score 5):

Look at your standalone.xml configuration file. You should find something like that at the end of file.

```
<deployments>
  <deployment name="xxx.war" runtime-name="xxx-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
      <content sha1="48dce368e5e68e0cc533f57f90bae170c857b2ae"/>
  </deployment>
  <deployment name="xxx1.war" runtime-name="xxx1-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
      <content sha1="9d8f243bc625da8ace475e62f89c3b09d46b4526"/>
  </deployment>   
  <deployment name="xxx2.war" runtime-name="xxx2-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.war">
      <content sha1="30678065aada0876c7350e0911fe37b757ec1a54"/>
  </deployment>
```

Just remove them if any..

Comment: I dont have this block in my standalone.xml i found it in wildfly-14.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration is that right?

Comment: @stakahop - the deployment won't be referenced in the xml file unless deployed via the management console - for standalone mode, it normally just gets dropped into ./standalone/deployments